# Using R, where can I get daily stock data that has a timestamp for when the low and the high of the day occurred?

Tags: r, quantmod

In the quantmod package of R, I use getSymbols to pull daily returns data. The free data comes from yahoo. However, it does not have the timestamp of when the high and low occurred during the day.

Is there a way to get that for free?

Comment: tidyquant has some nice api's

Comment: For free would mean building it yourself. You would need intraday data from tiingo, alphavantage or some other data provider and collect the data yourself in a database. Then you can find the info you want. You might want to browse quant.stackexchange.com to see if there is a suggestion to your query.